# PWA creates IndexedDB database, but does not create any object stores

Tags: progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have a Vue PWA and it stopped creating my IndexDB object stores on first load or upgrade.  Here is my code, I am using the latest version of IDB (https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb):

```
await openDB('dbname', 1, {
        upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
            switch (newVersion) {
                case 0:
                // a placeholder case so that the switch block will
                // execute when the database is first created
                // (oldVersion is 0)
                // falls through
                case 1:
                    db.createObjectStore('change_log', {keyPath: 'id'});
                    db.createObjectStore('person', {keyPath: 'id'})
                        .createIndex('username', 'username');
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried multiple browsers and incognito tabs, etc. and the same thing always happens.  The database is created, but no object stores are created.  I use developer tools to clear all the data in the PWA and refresh but the same thing happens.

If I increment the version number, the version of my database gets updated in the browser, but the object stores still do not get added.

The upgrade() function does not get called.

I had this happen to me earlier in my development, and I fixed it, but I can't remember how.  I feel like it may not actually be a coding issue...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem.  I added a logging mechanism to my App and there was code running BEFORE my upgrade code that was opening the database to create a log entry.  Therefore, it was creating the database (with no object stores) before my upgrade method was being called.  I changed my open database code to always include the upgrade method to solve my problems.